# How to make infinite Rest API requests and store the information?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

I want to create one request per second and store all the data in a txt file.

However, the saving of the tuples in the txt doesn't seem to work

```
import bybit
import pandas as pd
import time

#request data

client = bybit.bybit(test=True, api_key="", api_secret="")

data= client.Market.Market_orderbook(symbol="BTCUSD").result()


#create request loop 
h=1

while h>0:

    time.sleep(1)
    
    final = data + data

    #save in txt
    with open('orderbookdata.txt','w') as f:
        for tup in final:
            f.write( u" ".join(map(unicode,tup))+u"\n")
```

ps: keys given are read-only from a test net

Comment: Try opening it in mode `'a'` (append) instead of `'w'` (write). If a file is opened in write mode, it gets overwritten from the beginning.

Comment: Please, tell me these are not your *real* credentials.

Comment: keys given are read-only from a test net

Comment: Just for your info: there's an [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65620919/revisions).

Comment: @KlausD. no problem at all . thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply save each data to a new line, which requires you to open the file for appending, not writing.

```
with open('file', 'a') # open for appending
```

Appending would create a file if it is non-existent, but if it is, it wouldn't just create an empty one, like writing do, but appending to the end of the file.

---

First of all, an infinite while should be `while True:`, second, you are reading the value once, then you are saving that data each line. Making a request each second may not permitted by the site, check that in the docs.

```
import bybit
import pandas as pd
import time

client = bybit.bybit(test=True, api_key="DzX0ObRek383f7BP4f", api_secret="wjZKH8MKJehLXv4iTplJiSxn1bg8rw49Vlbt")

while True:
    data = client.Market.Market_orderbook(symbol="BTCUSD").result() #reading data each run
    with open('orderbookdata.txt','a') as f: #open for appending
        f.write('{}\n'.format(data)) #write data into a new line
    time.sleep(1) #sleep
```